# How do I convert existing promisified functions to async await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a library of functions that were originally callbacks. I've used Bluebird to promisify them all. I'd now like to take it to the next step and support async await on them. How can I achieve this?

Also is it possible to achieve this without breaking backwards compatibility?

---

Bergi's answer below answers the question. I had misread the documentation and got confused with use of async/await.

Comment: Can you post a sample code?

Comment: You have to do nothing to achieve that. It already works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promisified function will always returns promises, and therefore supports to be used with `async`/`await` out of the box. Remember that `await` is nothing but sugar for `then()` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I read that you can only call `await` on a function declared with `async`. Re-reading the documentation it seems that you can only use `await` within methods declared with `async`. Thanks